# Sorting Nested JSON in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, sorting

Is it possible to sort the following kind of nested JSON in python3 based on the Key "age"

```
{
   "barcelona":[
      {
         "age":29,
         "name":"john"
      }
   ],
   "london":[
      {
         "age":23,
         "name":"bob"
      }
   ],
   "mancherster":[
      {
         "age":23,
         "name":"shaw"
      }
   ],
   "paris":[
      {
         "age":45,
         "name":"bony"
      },
      {
         "age":16,
         "name":"paul"
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your responses

Comment: yes, it's possible. what have you tried?

Comment: I tried the following 

json_str = {"barcelona":[{"age":29,"name":"john"}],"london":[{"age":23,"name":"bob"}],"mancherster":[{"age":66,"name":"shaw"}],"paris":[{"age":23,"name":"bony"},{"age":44,"name":"paul"}]}
    print(json_str)
    json_obj = json.loads(json.dumps((json_str)))
    by_age = { key: sorted(value, key=lambda v: v['age']) for key, value in json_obj.items() }
    print(by_age)

Comment: `    json_str = {"barcelona":[{"age":29,"name":"john"}],"london":[{"age":23,"name":"bob"}],"mancherster":[{"age":66,"name":"shaw"}],"paris":[{"age":23,"name":"bony"},{"age":44,"name":"paul"}]}
    print(json_str) 
    json_obj = json.loads(json.dumps((json_str)))  <br/>
    by_age = { key: sorted(value, key=lambda v: v['age']) for key, value in json_obj.items() }  
    print(by_age)`

Comment: Please, edit your question to include all relevant information. Don't post important information in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just want to sort the lists for each city? In that case this should work:

```
import json   

json_str = "<your json string>"
json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
by_age = { key: sorted(value, key=lambda v: v['age']) for key, value in json_obj.items() }
```

Btw, there are errors in the JSON you posted - trailing commas (the commas at the end of `"name": "whatever",` in this case) are not allowed. You need to remove them to avoid an error at the `json.loads` call.

Comment: Hello Magnus, thanks for your response. 
I want to sort the entire JSON list based on AGE.

Comment: I tried the following code but the result is still not sorted
`code`
import json
json_str = {"barcelona":[{"age":29,"name":"john"}],"london":[{"age":23,"name":"bob"}],"mancherster":[{"age":66,"name":"shaw"}],"paris":[{"age":23,"name":"bony"},{"age":44,"name":"paul"}]}
    print(json_str)
    json_obj = json.loads(json.dumps((json_str)))
    by_age = { key: sorted(value, key=lambda v: v['age']) for key, value in json_obj.items() }
    print(by_age)

Comment: Well the thing is that your JSON contains a dictionary, not a list. So I'm unsure what result you are looking for. `age` is a key in the dicts ("person") contained in lists ("people"), which are again assigned to the keys in a dict ("cities"). My code sorts "people", the only lists in your JSON.